# ¿Qué es la "testiculina"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, significado

**Testiculina** no aparece en el DLE, pero parece ser una palabra utilizada con frecuencia, como
[aquí](https://www.cuartopoder.es/ideas/2017/04/04/patriotas/)

> ...que defiende el modelo de selección de Del Bosque (tiqui taca) frente al de Camacho (**testiculina**).

[aquí](http://www.lyricsondemand.com/letras/r/rodrigoletras/unlargocaminoalcieloletras.html)

> Un largo camino al cielo, **testiculina** de macho,
> te extrañaran mis mañanas, tu mi amigo yo tu hermano.

[o aquí](http://es.ign.com/movies/71956/news/critica-de-300-el-origen-de-un-imperio)

> La fórmula es tan simple como efectiva: **testiculina**, esteroides, acción estilizada, sangre a borbotones y personajes de una pieza.

La intuición me sugiere que sería algo así como "extracto de testículos" o "secreción de testículos", pero el que antaño pensara que "mamporrero" es el que "distribuye mamporros" y no su significado real me ha hecho más cauto con las especulaciones.

Comment: No estoy seguro pero diría que es algo como "echarle huevos" o "ser el más macho" o similar. He encontrado más usos de la palabra en otros artículos y diría que es eso: "afrontar con valentía masculina", "jugarse la vida por orgullo de hombre"

Comment: No creo que exista tal cosa. Parece una palabra usada en la prensa deportiva para aludir a la "masculinidad" de los deportista, las mujeres no se que tendrán en ese caso.

Comment: @blonfu ovarilina?

Answer (score 4):

Yo creo que significa exactamente lo que parece. Diría que se trata de un neologismo que aplica el sufijo *-ina*:

> **[-ina](http://dle.rae.es/?id=L9vjZMs)**
>
> Del lat. *-īna*.
>
> 5. suf. En química, indica sustancia relacionada con lo denotado por el elemento principal de la palabra. *Adrenalina, cocaína, morfina, cafeína.*

Si te fijas, en el último ejemplo se habla de "fórmula" (con alusión a las fórmulas químicas), "esteroides" (una sustancia química biológica) y otros conceptos biológicos, lo que induce a pensar con poco lugar a dudas de que significa "sustancia relacionada con los testículos", es decir, una forma de aludir a la hombría.

Comment: Seguro que tienes razón, pero me gusta confirmarlo. Desde que vi que **mamporro**: De mano1 y porra. 1. m. coloq. Golpe, coscorrón, puñetazo. y **mamporrero**: De *mamporro*. 1. m. y f. Persona que dirige el miembro del caballo en el acto de la cópula.  , tiendo a ser muy cuidadoso en las suposuciones "lógicas"

Comment: Si _mamporro_ viene de _mano_ y _porra_, si pones tu "mano" en la "porra" del caballo eres un mamporrero. :-D Bromas aparte, haces bien en preguntar, y no es una pregunta tonta en base a los votos que estás recibiendo. No tengo nada para argumentar mi respuesta más allá de lo que cada uno entiende en base a tus ejemplos. En mi caso coincido con tu opinión.

Comment: Concretando un poco más todo lo que habéis dicho, a mí me parece una forma humorística de referirse a la testosterona.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo: ¿con la misma lógica no podría ser un eufemismo para *semen*?

Comment: @Luis no te digo que no, pero ese eufemismo lo veo más en el segundo ejemplo. En el tercero no lo tengo claro y en el primero no lo veo para nada.